# Find all kinds of diagonals of length 3 elements in a 4 * 4 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm sure this question has been raised, but unfortunately I can't find anything similar. I must say right away that I am not asking for a solution in the form of a code, I would like you to tell me where to start and what to be guided by when solving this problem.

The essence of the problem: I need to find all kinds of diagonals of length 3 elements in a 4 * 4 matrix. Take a look at an example

```
matrix = [
[1,2,3,4],
[11,12,13,14],
[21,22,23,24],
[31,32,33,34]]
```

output = [[1,12,23], [2,13,24], [11,22,33], [12,23,34], [4,13,22], [3,12,21], [14,23,32], [13,22,31]

In fact, my matrix is many times larger, but I think this small example is quite enough to describe the essence of the problem.

Comment: `arr[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]` gives you one diagonal.  Repeat for the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some key functions I would use to accomplish your goal:

- [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)
- [`np.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)
- [`np.fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html)

Let me know if you'd like more information ;)

---

Numpy has your back with vectorial code, no need to loop!

Setup:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

>>> matrix = [
... [1,2,3,4],
... [11,12,13,14],
... [21,22,23,24],
... [31,32,33,34]]
```

Create an array of every `(3, 3)` subwindow of the original array. We want to take the diagonals of each of the submatrices.

```
>>> windows = swv(matrix, (3, 3))
>>> windows
array([[[[ 1,  2,  3],
         [11, 12, 13],
         [21, 22, 23]],

        [[ 2,  3,  4],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [22, 23, 24]]],


       [[[11, 12, 13],
         [21, 22, 23],
         [31, 32, 33]],

        [[12, 13, 14],
         [22, 23, 24],
         [32, 33, 34]]]])
```

Extract the diagonals of every submatrix:

```
>>> diagonals = np.diagonal(windows, axis1=-2, axis2=-1)
>>> diagonals
array([[[ 1, 12, 23],
        [ 2, 13, 24]],

       [[11, 22, 33],
        [12, 23, 34]]])
```

If you flip each submatrix horizontally, you can do the same trick to get the antidiagonals (upper right -> lower left)

```
>>> anti_diagonals = np.diagonal(windows[..., ::-1], axis1=-2, axis2=-1)
>>> anti_diagonals
array([[[ 3, 12, 21],
        [ 4, 13, 22]],

       [[13, 22, 31],
        [14, 23, 32]]])
```

Finally, combine them together:

```
>>> np.vstack([
...     diagonals.reshape(-1, 3),
...     anti_diagonals.reshape(-1, 3)
... ])
array([[ 1, 12, 23],
       [ 2, 13, 24],
       [11, 22, 33],
       [12, 23, 34],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [ 4, 13, 22],
       [13, 22, 31],
       [14, 23, 32]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the matrix rows and columns to identify the starting points for the diagonals, then collect the three elements from each diagonal

Answer (score 0):

One diagonal:

```
In [577]: x = (np.arange(4)*10)[:,None]+np.arange(1,5); x
Out[577]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [31, 32, 33, 34]])

In [578]: idx=np.arange(3); x[idx,idx]
Out[578]: array([ 1, 12, 23])
```

another set of diagonals:

```
In [582]: idx1 = idx+np.array([0,0,1,1])[:,None]; idx1
Out[582]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [583]: idx2 = idx+np.array([0,1,0,1])[:,None]; idx2
Out[583]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [584]: x[idx1, idx2]
Out[584]: 
array([[ 1, 12, 23],
       [ 2, 13, 24],
       [11, 22, 33],
       [12, 23, 34]])
```

Reverse the columns to get the other set:

```
In [585]: x[:,::-1][idx1, idx2]
Out[585]: 
array([[ 4, 13, 22],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [14, 23, 32],
       [13, 22, 31]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with my own solution, slightly different from Chrysophylaxs recommendations. But it solves my problem. (the length of the diagonal is 3 characters, so in the code I need to specify this (3,3))

```
grid_np = np.array(grid)
list_with_diagonal = []
view_shape = tuple(np.subtract(grid_np.shape, (3,3)) + 1) + (3,3)
arr_view = as_strided(grid_np, view_shape, grid_np.strides * 2)
for main in arr_view:
    for submain in main:
        first = submain.diagonal()
        second = fliplr(submain).diagonal()
        list_with_diagonal.append(first.tolist())
        list_with_diagonal.append(second.tolist())
```